# How to solve PHP Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: indexing, undefined

I'm getting these errors when loggin in on the site:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebuy\catalog\controller\module\boss_megamenu.php on line 173
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebuy\catalog\controller\module\boss_megamenu.php on line 177
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: category_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebuy\catalog\controller\module\boss_megamenu.php on line 178

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use either

1. `@$variable` - Only use this if it doesn't matter if the variable is set
2. `isset($variable){ // some code }` - use this if the variable has to be set